# One-sided inverse of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

Is it possible to find an example of an one-sided inverse of a function?  other than matrix?

I am trying to find such an example but having no luck. Anybody got an idea about it?

Comment: The Ur-example must be the integral and derivative on say, the space of continuously differentiable functions on a closed interval.

Comment: @saulspatz: That's rather abstract. Why not just a projection?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's another example: 
Let $f:\Bbb R\to[0,\infty)$ be defined by $f(x)=x^2$, and $g:[0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ by $g(x)=\sqrt x$.

Now,
$$(f\circ g)(x)=\sqrt x^2=x,$$
but
$$(g\circ f)(x)=\sqrt{x^2}=|x|.$$

Comment: Wow !!! Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: The domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$. When you square the elements from domain of f, it clearly falls in the domain of g and then the output is $\sqrt{x^2}$. Because $x\in \mathbb{R}$, this equals $|x|$. I think, there is no flaw in this example.

Comment: @Mr.MBB If you like it, upvote it.  :)

Comment: @ Tim Raczkowski I really like your example. My vote doesn't count because I have only 11 reputation. Please upvote my question to reach 15 reputation. Thanks !!!

Comment: Your welcome.  Also don't forget to accept one of the replies as the answer.

Answer (score 13):

Think of the function $f:\{0,1\}\to \{1\}$ that is constant. It has a right inverse $g:\{1\}\to\{0,1\}$ which maps $1\mapsto 1$. This is because $f\circ g=Id_{\{1\}}$, the identity function on $\{1\}$. But it doesn't have a left inverse since it is not injective (1 to 1).

Also you should notice that the right inverse $g$ isn't even unique.

Answer (score 5):

Examples are abundant. Some basic facts may help you find many:

1. *If $\:f\colon X\to Y$ has a left inverse $h\colon Y\to X$ ($h\circ f = id_X$), then $f$ is a injection and $h$ is a surjection.*
2. *If $\:f\colon X\to Y$ has a right inverse $g\colon Y\to X$ ($f\circ g = id_Y$), then $f$ is a surjection and $g$ is an injection.*

   (*Proof of 2.*) $f$ is a surjection: if $y\in Y$ but $y\notin range(f)$, then $y\ne f(g(y))$, so $f\circ g \ne  id_Y$.

   $g$ is an injection: if $y_1, y_2\in Y$ and $g(y_1) = g(y_2)$; then $y_1 = f(g(y_1)) = f(g(y_2)) = y_2$.

   (*Proof of 1.*) Given the hypothesis, $h$ has a right inverse $f$, so by 2., $h$ is a surjection and $f$ is an injection.

   *Note*: a right inverse for $f$ is a *choice function* for the indexed family of nonempty sets $\{f^{-1}(y)\mid y\in Y\}$. An equivalent form of the Axiom of Choice is: *Every surjection has a right inverse*. By contrast, it's easy to prove in ZF that every injection on a nonempty set has a left inverse.

Now you can characterize a bijection as a function that has both one-sided inverses:

3. *If $f$ has a right inverse $g$ and a left inverse $h$ then $g = h = f^{-1}$ and $f$ is a bijection.*

   Consider: $h = h\circ id_Y = h\circ (f\circ g) = (h\circ f) \circ g = id_X \circ g = g$.

---

Matrix multiplication is actually a relevant analogy. 
Matrices represent functions, linear maps, and composition of linear maps corresponds to multiplication of their associated matrices.

An $n\times m$ matrix $A$ represents a linear map, a function $T_A\colon\Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$ that computes $\vec{x}\mapsto A\cdot \vec{x}$, multiplication of an m-vector by $A$, yielding an $n$-vector. Thus $T_{AB} = T_A\circ T_B$, and $T_{I_m} = id_{\Bbb R^m}$.

When $m>n$, there are no injective linear maps $\Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$, just as there are no injections from $X\to Y$ if (and only if) $card(Y)< card(X)$. (By definition, $card(X)\le card(Y)$ iff there is an injection $X\to Y$.) So if $Y$ is smaller than $X$, then given $X\stackrel{f}{\to} Y\stackrel{g}{\to} X$, $f$ isn't an injection and $g\circ f \ne id_X$.

For matrices $A$ and $B$ of sizes $n\times m$ and $m\times n$ respectively, both products $AB$ and $BA$ are defined. Both $\operatorname{rank} A$ and $\operatorname{rank} B$ are $\le \min(n,m)$, so if $n\ne m$, then one of the matrices has to lose information — it has a nontrivial kernel, multiplying by it on the left is not 1-1 — and one of the products will not be the identity.

1. *If $A$ is $n\times m$ and $A$ has a left inverse, then $m\le n$ and $T_A$ is an injection.* Suppose $BA=I_m$ and $n<m$. Then the rank of $A$ is at most $n$, and then the rank of $BA$ is also at most $n$. But the rank of $I_m$ is $m >n$. (In fact, $\operatorname{rank} A = m$.)
2. *If $A$ is $n\times m$ and $A$ has a right inverse, then $n\le m$ and $T_A$ is a surjection.* If $AB = I_m$, then $A$ is a left inverse of $B$, so this follows from the previous result.

Answer (score 4):

Another classical example is the shift maps. Let $S$ be the space of real sequences $S = \{(a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots) : a_i\in\mathbb{R} \, \text{for all $i$}\}$ (which, essentially, is the space of functions $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$).

Define the "left shift map" $f:S\to S$ as
$$
f((a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)) = (a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots)
$$
(i.e., remove the first element from the sequence), and the "right shift map" $g:S\to S$ as
$$
g((a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots)) = (0,a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots)
$$
(i.e., add a zero at the beginning of the sequence).

Then, $f\circ g$ is the identity, but $g\circ f$ is not.